# angular - how to create components that don't interfere with component and style hierarchies?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 4 as an example but this question applies to angular in general.

Below is a basic ion page for a list and a pull down refresher.

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" pullMin="100" (ionRefresh)="onRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item></ion-item>
    </ion-list>
<ion-content>
```

The ion-refresher must sit directly inside ion-content or it won't work propertly. The example below doesn't display the refresher icons and loading

```html
<ion-content>
<div>
    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" pullMin="100" (ionRefresh)="onRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item></ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

The same general issue happens when I move everything inside a custom angular component

```html
<ion-content>
    <app-ion-refresher-list></app-ion-refresher-list>
<ion-content>

// component selector = 'app-ion-refresher-list'
```

Likewise some style might get messed up when I create a component for ion-item and place it inside ion-list.

```html
<ion-list>
    <app-ion-item></app-ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In both cases I expect, that there are some hierarchical dependencies of styles or ng-content projections

```css
ion-list ion-item{
 styles...
}
```

So is there a way I can create an angular component without introducing an "extra" element layer in order to keep the styles and functions working?

What I want is basically the same feature for components what ng-container does.

Comment: Hi @kuldeep.kamboj I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Could you please elaborate?